# Get the latest email from an email address using imap-simple in node

Tags: node.js, email, imap

I want to get the latest email from the email address using imap. I was using searchCriteria 1:2 but I am getting oldest 2 emails, I also used 'NEW' and 'RECENT' but that is also not working. How can I fetch latest emails of my inbox. Here is my code:

```
   var imaps = require('imap-simple'); 
 var config = {
imap: {
  user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
  password: 'xxxxx',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  authTimeout: 3000
 }
};
   imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {
return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
  var searchCriteria = [
      'UNSEEN'
  ];
  var fetchOptions = 
    { bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'], struct: true }

  return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (messages) {
    messages.forEach(function (message) {
console.log(message.parts[0].body);
});
  });
});
```

});

Comment: Try `'from "noreply@google.com"'`. I'm quite puzzled by your attempts so far. [Here is the list of what each search key does](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-51), `new` and `unseen` aren't even a little like what you want, or do I misunderstand completely?

Comment: @arnt Sorry. I wrongly framed the question. I have edited it now. Actually I wanted latest emails from my inbox. So how should I use searchCriteria.

Comment: Apparently not possible with imap-simple, AFAICT. I'm amazed by some of the questions here. People think they need to issue a server search whose result is always "1 2 3 4 5 6 ... n" where n is a number the client already has. In this case, you want something like "1234:1238" to get the last five, and the 1238 is a number that imap-simple received from the server as part of openBox(), and openBox() discarded instead of telling you. Time for you to [contribute a patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap-simple#contributing) to provide access to the "EXISTS" or the "UNSEEN" numbers.

Comment: Oops, that should be EXISTS or UIDNEXT, not EXISTS or UNSEEN. You could work around it by using node-imap's status() call before openBox().